# "framework not found AFNetworking for architecture arm64" for my Test Target

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

This is what I see when trying to run tests under test target in my iOS App:

> ld: framework not found AFNetworking for architecture arm64
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

This is how my podfile looks like:

```
use_frameworks!
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, "8.2"

def pods

    pod 'AFNetworking'
    pod 'Fabric'
    pod 'Crashlytics'
    pod 'MagicalRecord'
    pod 'SDWebImage'
    pod 'SVProgressHUD'
end

target 'MySoberRoomMate' do
    pods
end

inhibit_all_warnings!
```

Answer (score 3):

I am new on IOS development and did not have the required reputation to add comment so that I am posting answer.

I did a little work with pod file and i think the pods for the test target is not added in pod file so that the compiler showing the error.

do some thing like this in the pod file for the test target

```
target 'TestTarget' do
    pods
end
```

add your test target name in place of 'TestTarget'

Hope it works.

Comment: I think it is not this, but try... let you know. It doesnt have to be included like this.

Comment: Yes, you were right, it worked, but it is straight, because in previous app, I havent done it, but it worked also.

Comment: i did not know much about it but as i said we have to tell that which target or targets are depending on the pod files.
Kindly Tick and up vote.
i helps me to get required reputation to add comment.